# Make won't recognize that files are being modified

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, gnu-make

I'm attempting to run an echo command in a Makefile when my .cpp files are modified.

**Makefile:**

```
src/*.cpp:
   echo 'file has changed'
```

**Command line:**

```
$ mingw32-make.exe
mingw32-make: 'src/main.cpp' is up to date.
```

I'm confused as to why this says `main.cpp` is up to date, even after I modify it. Shouldn't it output `file has changed`?

**Version info:**

```
$ mingw32-make.exe --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for i686-w64-mingw32
```

Comment: Is that your *real* makefile?  A wildcard in a makefile is `%` rather than `*`.

Comment: @G.M. changing `*` to `%` results in `mingw32-make: *** No targets.  Stop.` even when I modify any of the .cpp files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a target that depends on your *.cpp files:

```
cpp_files_are_up_to_date: src/*.cpp
    echo 'files have changed'
    echo.>cpp_files_are_up_to_date
```

Comment: Why can't the date of modification for the .cpp files be compared to anything? Printing 'file has changed' 100% of the time doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: That just outputs `mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target '*.cpp', needed by 'cpp_files_are_up_to_date'.  Stop.`

Comment: Try replacing your entire makefile with just this auxiliary target.

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: In my answer I made the target dependent on '*.cpp' and not 'src/*.cpp' like in your question. Try changing that.

Comment: I modified it as you said and now it outputs this: `echo 'files have changed'
'files have changed'
touch cpp_files_are_up_to_date
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, touch cpp_files_are_up_to_date, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified. mingw32-make: *** [cpp_files_are_up_to_date] Error 2
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'cpp_files_are_up_to_date' failed`

Comment: I don't know mingw and I don't have a Windows machine but it looks like you can't create a file because the `touch` command is missing or broken. You basically need to create a file with the name of the target. This may be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/10426/windows-equivalent-of-the-linux-command-touch

Comment: Using `echo.>cpp_files_are_up_to_date` makes it so that the commands run when any .cpp files are modified! Finally! Thanks so much!

Comment: @mkcms: Please add *why* this is necessary - namely, `make` determines whether a file needs to be updated by *comparing* its modification time to that of another file.  It doesn't keep a memory of states of files in the past.